# How to redraw widget on Flutter when a value changes?

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose the following simple `StatefulWidget` example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int value = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App Example')),
        body: Row(children:[
          Text("hello"), 
          RaisedButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: (){setState(() { value+=1; });},
            child: new Text("Add"),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My main problem is: how do I redraw `Text("hello")` every time  `value` changes? I'm using `Text` as an example, but it could be an widget that has an internal state, and I'd like to redraw it when the value changes. It does not necessarily depends on the `value` but I want to redraw anyways when `value` changes.

Comment: But everything you wrote is write, you can test it, by setting Text("hello $value") for example, state will updated because you used setState in onPressed method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea ab8 it. I do this kind of stuff by wrapping it into an container and setting height and width equal to some variable.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is if you just want to change the state of that specific widget(Example the Text widget) without disturbing the other widgets. [This](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) are some of the state management's which might help other than SetState (My personal fav. BLOC and REDUx).

Answer (score 0):

Update this line:-
**Text("hello ${value}"),**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int value = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App Example')),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(children: [
            Text("hello ${value}"),
            RaisedButton(
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  value += 1;
                });
              },
              child: new Text("Add"),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes the `Text` or whatever widget dependent on the value. I do not want it to depend on the value